# Bitmovin and Exoplayer conflicting dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, exoplayer, gradle-dependencies, bitmovin-player

I am using both Exoplayer and Bitmovin libraries in my project

```
compile "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:$rootConfiguration.exoPlayerVersion"
compile "com.bitmovin.analytics:collector:$rootConfiguration.bitmovinVersion"
```

and:

```
exoPlayerVersion = '2.8.4'
bitmovinVersion = '1.3.8'
```

When I run my app it gives me this error

```
`AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present: `com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.hls.BuildConfig","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

How can I exclude `Exoplayer` files from `Bitmovin`?

P.S. It was working fine until version 1.2.0

Answer (score 3):

To `Exoplayer` files from `Bitmovin` library just change your dependency like this:

```
compile("com.bitmovin.analytics:collector:$rootConfiguration.bitmovinVersion") {
        // Necessary to avoid version conflicts
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.exoplayer', module: 'exoplayer'
        // Or simply
        exclude module: 'exoplayer'
    }
```

Comment: I used the following code and it worked but there are other complexities using proguard now:
compile ("com.bitmovin.analytics:collector:$rootConfiguration.bitmovinVersion"){
        exclude group: 'com.bitmovin.player', module: 'exoplayer-smoothstreaming'
        exclude group: 'com.bitmovin.player', module: 'exoplayer-hls'
        exclude group: 'com.bitmovin.player', module: 'exoplayer-dash'
        exclude group: 'com.bitmovin.player', module: 'exoplayer-core'
        exclude group: 'com.bitmovin.player', module: 'exoplayer-ui'
    }

Comment: Why you exclude the com.bitmovin.player modules? usually is not a good practice to remove library modules especially the related libraries like this unless stated by its developers. For proguard did you added the recommended setting? 
-keep class com.bitmovin.player.** { *; }
-keep interface com.bitmovin.player.** { *; }

Comment: Excluding individual modules worked : exclude module: 'exoplayer-smoothstreaming'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-hls'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-dash'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-core'
        exclude module: 'exoplayer-ui'
Yes I added those settings for proguard but still getting this error : com.bitmovin.player.a.d.a.a: can't find referenced method 'com.google.android.exoplayer2.text.ttml.TtmlDecoder$FrameAndTickRate parseFrameAndTickRates(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser)' in program class com.bitmovin.player.a.d.a.a

Comment: Is it ok when proguard isn't running? Please create a new question and attach your proguard file.

Comment: Alright. I think it is do with latest release of Bitmovin. It was working fine until 1.2.0. Will create a separate question for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To enable the coexistence of both, the Bitmovin Player Android SDK is also available as a separate artifact that evades namespace collisions and is marked with the +jason suffix in the player version:

https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/faqs/can-i-use-exoplayer-and-the-bitmovin-player-android-sdk-in-the-same-project